# Getting error when sending data through form (Office365)

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to debug this issue when sending this information from a form, but I keep getting this error.

```
error '8004020e'
/contacthandler.asp, line 45
```

I have not done much work in asp, but I've managed to clean this file up a little bit from the previous developer (still had the error). The error happens at the `.Send`..forgot to clarify that.

Here is the code. Any help is appreciated.

```
'declare variables
dim name, phone, email, comment, service, returnPage

'set variables to the corresponding fields from contact form
name = request.form("custName")
phone = request.form("custPhone")
email = request.form("custEmail")
comment = request.form("custNotes")
service = request.form("service")
returnPage = request.form("page")

dim theEmail
' set the email content data
theEmail = "<h3>Contact from website, information below.</h3><table border='0'><tr><th>Customer Name:<td>"&name
theEmail = theEmail&"<tr><th>Phone Number:<td>"&phone&"<tr><th>Email Address:<td>"&email&"<tr><th>Service Category:<td>"&service
theEmail = theEmail&"<tr><th valign='top'>Comments/Notes:<td>"&comment&"</table>"

' send the email

dim sch
sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/" 

Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 


With cdoConfig.Fields 
    .Item(sch & "sendusing") = 2 ' cdoSendUsingPort 
    .Item(sch & "smtpserverport") = 587
    .Item(sch & "smtpserver") = "smtp.office365.com"
    .Item(sch & "smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item(sch & "sendusername") = "########"
    .Item(sch & "sendpassword") = "########"
    .update 
End With 

Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

With cdoMessage 
    Set .Configuration = cdoConfig 
    .From = name & "<" & email & ">" 
    .To = "info@mywebsite.com" 
    .Subject = "Website - "&service&" Request" 
    .HTMLBody = theEmail
    .Send 
End With 

Set cdoMessage = Nothing 
Set cdoConfig = Nothing 


'response.write "sent, check the mail"
response.redirect "thankyou.asp"
'returnPage&".asp"
```

Comment: Which line of your code is line 45?

Comment: That would be the .Send

Answer (score 0):

MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527318%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx) suggests you need to format your `.From` field as follows:

```
.From """" & name & """ <" & email & ">"
```

Comment: Also where do you get the variables name and email from?

Comment: Same error and the variables name and email come from request.form("custName") and request.form("custEmail)"

Comment: Would it be possible to post all the rest of the code to the page? It might improve the chances of finding a solution.

Comment: Found this link. My only thought..is the smtp address bad?

http://www.bebosoft.com/support/knowledge-base/forms-to-go/46-asp/83-error-8004020e

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34940/discussion-between-castrohenge-and-wowzuzz)

Answer (score 0):

I used Google to look up the error code and I found lots of sites they meant there is an issue with sending the data. That can be another source of trouble.

What will happen if you replace

```
.Item(sch & "sendusing") = 2 ' cdoSendUsingPort
```

by

```
.Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = 1 'cdoSendUsingPickup
```

Additional try it without any comments.